# Using Numpy to multiply table row data

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to learn numpy for an imoplementation I have been working on.

I need to build a table. and multiply certain number of rows based on another set of rows. And then write the rows to a csv.

In Python I am doing something like this

```
def test_write():
    initial_rows_data_list = [1,2,3,4]
    multiplied_row_data = [["a","b","c","d","e"],["f","g","h"]]
    third_multiply = [["a1","a2","a3"],["a4","a5"]]

    row_list = []
    for mrd in multiplied_row_data:
        if third_multiply:
            for tm in third_multiply:
                written_row_data = []
                written_row_data.extend(mrd)
                written_row_data.extend(initial_rows_data_list)
                written_row_data.extend(tm)
                row_list.append(written_row_data)
        else:
            written_row_data = []
            written_row_data.extend(mrd)
            written_row_data.extend(initial_rows_data_list)
            row_list.append(written_row_data)


    return row_list


if __name__=="__main__":
    for row in test_write():
        csv.write(row)
```

So the desired output would be something like:

```
[
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'a4', 'a5'],
    ['f', 'g', 'h', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
    ['f', 'g', 'h', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'a4', 'a5']
]
```

The thing is the dataset I am working on is large. Could be 1000s of rows in either of the 2 lists.

I cannot use Pandas at all because I am on GAE and they do not allow native code to be run but allow numpy as a dependency. (Pandas has some native code of its own)

How do I multiply these rows and then write it to CSV/XLSX?

-Shaurya

Answer (score 1):

You don't need pandas to write to a CSV file.  You can use the csv module.

```
import csv 

// def test_write

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for row in test_write():
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

In addition, when dealing with large combinations of lists, it may be preferable to use a generator than to return a list after all the list elements are collected.  With a generator, list elements are "returned" as you go:

```
def test_write():
    initial_rows_data_list = [1,2,3,4]
    multiplied_row_data = [["a","b","c","d","e"],["f","g","h"]]
    third_multiply = [["a1","a2","a3"],["a4","a5"]]

    row_list = []
    for mrd in multiplied_row_data:
        written_row_data = []
        written_row_data.extend(mrd)
        written_row_data.extend(initial_rows_data_list)
        if third_multiply:
            for tm in third_multiply:
                yield written_row_data + tm
        else:
            yield written_row_data
```